# Floated legend within fieldset not displaying correctly in newest version of Chrome (Version 55)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is the HTML and CSS in question:

```css
legend {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Test</legend>
</fieldset>
```

This will show "Test" in FireFox, IE, Edge, and Chrome 54. In the new version of Chrome you will not see any words at all.

Is there any way to fix this issue within Chrome (Version 55)?

Comment: I don't see problems with your short code; could you post a more complete example?

Comment: This is all the code that is necessary to reproduce the issue. This issue is only in the latest version of Chrome (55). Here is a jsbin example : https://jsbin.com/hodolejuyu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Looking at the [spec for `legend`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendered-legend), 1 of the 3 requirements for `legend` is that it not be positioned. Depending how Chrome chose to implement the spec this time around, floating `legend` may have invalidated the element as a valid `legend` and thus not rendering it? Just a guess though.

Comment: I think chrome has issues with legend tag....may be you consider using positioning absolute/relative instead of float or just use display:inline-block

Comment: @geeky We have tried to add "position: relative;" which will display the legend, but it pushes any other elements within that fieldset to the side instead of rendering the legend above the other elements. This does not occur in Firefox or Edge, and it didn't occur in any previous versions of Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I had to update the browser to see the issue; It seems a bug

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Ie-FkIBHrYk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a bug in Chrome**

> Floating legend should be added to the fieldset's anonymous block.
>
> If fieldset's legend is floating it should be added to the existing
>   fieldset\'s anonymous block instead of creating a nested one. This is
>   necessary because flexbox forces the floating legend to be
>   non-floating and therefore if the legend needs to be floating it
>   should be added to the fieldset's anonymous block.
>
> BUG=661230, 670837
>
> TEST=fast/forms/fieldset/fieldset-legend-float.html
>
> Tested with real world websites:
>
> - https://jsbin.com/zutekilusi/1/edit?html,css,output
> - http://www.timico.co.uk/timico-ltd-application-form
> - http://codepen.io/michaelpumo/pen/VmZqrr
> - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ActiveUsers
> - https://jsfiddle.net/tdbthtra/
>
> Review-Url: https://codereview.chromium.org/2550963002

Chromium Git - https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/0f77a4ef8c0218492b5b8689a793b34b0f5a34d8

The following bug reports have been raised:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=670837
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=661230

**What can we do?**

The bug has been fixed in the latest raw build downloaded from https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ and appears that it is planned to be merged into version 55 within the next few days:

> Merge approved for M55 branch 2883; I will also approve for M56 branch 2924 but let's not process that until we have confirmation that everything looks good tomorrow.

Legend float in fieldset makes legend disappear (Comment 56) - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=670837#c56

In the meantime a temporary solution could be to replace the `fieldset` that contains the `legend` with a `div`:

```css
legend {
  float: left;
}
div {
  border: 2px groove threedface;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Label</legend>
  <p>Label doesn't show</p>
</fieldset>
<div>
  <legend>Label</legend>
  <p>does show</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 12/12/16**

Appears the issue has now been corrected by Google as it no longer occurs in Version 55.0.2883.87 m.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. We received a response from Google as well.

Comment: @Frightener77 Just tested this and it appears that Google have corrected the issue in Version 55.0.2883.87 m.